# Passing jade variables as parameteres to jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, pug

A night of fun.

The standard template of

```
#{media[i+2]._id}
```

Works most of the time... but being able to pass this spaghetti code into jQuery functions is becoming impossible for me.

Here's the options I've tried:

```
input.btn.btn-success(onclick='UpdateStatus(#{media[i+2]._id})', type='button', value='Approve')
```

Will not work.  Will give me an illegal token error.

However if I inspect the element it's what I wanted.......

```
<a href="#" onclick="UpdateStatus(5224207bc90df58486947d70)" class="btn btn-success">Approve</a>
```

Really stuck guys, thanks for the help!

Rob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try this:

```
onclick='UpdateStatus("#{media[i+2]._id}")'
```

Comment: That did the trick! Andres was right - I didn't realize the ID was HEX and so it needed the quotes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is:

```
onclick="UpdateStatus(&quot;5224207bc90df58486947d70&quot;)"
```

Note the added quotes, since it's not a number but a hex string. Thus:

```
input.btn.btn-success(onclick='UpdateStatus("#{media[i+2]._id}")', type='button', value='Approve')
```

Comment: Thank you man - so appreciated the new "set of eyes" to look at it.  Never thought about the ID being hex